# how do I fix / repair drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

I don't know how to phrase this.

But the drive (E:) as shown in the picture is not functional.
I can't open it or right-click it.
It doesn't show errors, rather keeps loading and then freezes.

It's an internal HDD in one partition.
It's fully empty (has no data).

How do I fix it?

Another important thing to mention,
the PC was not used in months and when I opened it it said repairing Drive E: before it booted up.

[image]

Comment: Start with a bootable Windows 10 USB and see if you can see / access the drive. Try the drive in another computer to see if you can see / access the drive.  Otherwise it may have gone bad and needs to be replaced.

Comment: Open it in diskmgmt.msc or DiskGenius and check its status. Repair, or format if necessary -- though formatting will certainly destroy any data.

Answer (score 0):

Only two options : Either the disk or its cable have gone bad.

Check all connectors, try another cable, or try the disk in another
computer.

If nothing works, it's time to buy a new disk.